# Azure app service, intermittently slow file post

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have an app that allows users to upload a ~2MB file which is then saved in Azure blob storage. The app has been working fine for years and then a few days ago, we started intermittently seeing extremely slow response times on the file upload controller action. Normally, file uploads take only a second or less, but now, intermittently and seemingly randomly, they are taking up to 60 seconds.

The file is being passed into the action method as an IFormFile.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddFile(IFormFile file)
{
}
```

The odd thing is, when we look at the app insights logs for these long requests, the dependency calls are all very quick and don't nearly add up to the total request duration. It's almost as if the request hits some sort of delay before any action method code executes. You can see this in the screen shot below, all of those dependencies happen during the last second of request execution. The 1.1ms database call is also the first line of code in the action method we're uploading to, so I have no idea what's happening before that point. I'm sort of assuming it's waiting for all of the multipart request (the file attachment), but don't understand why this would sometimes take 50x times as long.

[image: e2e transaction]

We have not been able to reproduce the issue locally or on our test app service.

Does anyone have insights into what could cause this delay? I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting it.

Thanks!

Comment: From your description, I think the issue not related the code about uploading files. It sounds like high cpu issue, [you could follow the official blog to check it](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/10/05/Diagnose-App-with-High-CPU.html).

Comment: did you solve your issue?... we starting getting very slow response (progress) uploading to post action in an WebApp in azure without any code or configuration change!?